# Shifting values by groups

Tags: r

I have an unbalanced (unequal number of observations per observational unit) panel dataset. The dataset contains individual data of students and their institutional affiliations. The key information is whether or not they achieved an degree or dropped out.

In the example dataset below (df_raw), there are two variables describing if the student achieved an degree. My challenge is that the degree is not in all cases registered on the correct semester (due to delay in the adminstrations. The lag can be up to 2/3 semesters). Therefore, student 1 in the example dataset is registered to achieve an degree spring 2012. I would like move this value 1 to fall 2011 since that is when the degree was completed.

Student 2 changed institution after completing the degree at Harvard. And the degree is registered spring 2012, when the student started studying at Stanford. In this case I would like to move this value to the last semester at Harvard.

The wanted resulted is illustrated in df_complete (below). My dataset contains more than 30 000 students and 200 000 observations. Again: the dataset is unbalanced and the lag in registration of an degree varies case by case.

Please note: Harvard and Standford is only used as examples since they are known to most readers.

Thank you.

```
df_raw <- data.frame(
student = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
year = c(2010,2011,2011,2012,2010,2011,2011,2012,2012,2013),
semester = 
c("Fall","Spring","Fall","Spring","Fall","Spring","Fall","Spring","Fall",   
"Spring"),
institution = c("Stanford","Stanford","Stanford","Stanford","Harvard","Harvard","Harvard","Stanford","Stanford","Stanford"),
level = c("Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Higher 
degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower 
degree","Lower degree"),
degree_same = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
degree_other = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))

df_complete <- data.frame(
student = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
year = c(2010,2011,2011,2012,2010,2011,2011,2012,2012,2013),
semester = c("Fall","Spring","Fall","Spring","Fall","Spring","Fall","Spring","Fall",    "Spring"),
institution = c("Stanford","Stanford","Stanford","Stanford","Harvard","Harvard","Harvard","Stanford","Stanford","Stanford"),
level = c("Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Higher degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree","Lower degree"),
degree_same = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
degree_other = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))
```

Comment: Not very clear. What is `degree_same` and `degree_other`? Why is student 1 in 2012 for Higher degree 0 in degrees?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. `degree_same` = 1 if the student achieved the degree at the institution the student currently studies at. `degree_other` = 1 if the students degree is not achieved at the institution the student studies at.

This distinction is necessary since the registration of an degree often is delayed. The achieved lower degree of student 1 was registered when the student already had started his studies for a higher degree,